# Is possible to grab a pdf files from direct link to a folder in server?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, pdf

I just want to know if there is a method to grab a pdf file from a direct link like this :

```
http://domain.com/files/mvc.pdf
```

To a folder in the server for example :

```
host.com/files/
```

if there is a method for ASP MVC it will be great and thanks .

**Note** : I will use the method in my asp mvc application .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try WebClient

```
using (var webClient = new WebClient())
{ 
     webClient.DownloadFile("http://domain.com/files/mvc.pdf", Server.MapPath("~/files/mvc.pdf"));
}
```